# The use of logarithmic form to facilitate comparison

Tags: data-visualization, logarithm

On a post from the internet I've found the following expression, which I'll like to understand and to apply it on my datas.

> "Because of the size difference between the largest and the smallest
>   metros, the data is expressed in logarithmic form so as to facilitate
>   comparison."[[source]](http://www.theatlanticcities.com/jobs-and-economy/2012/04/why-bigger-cities-are-greener/863/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On normal scale the extreme points would be far from the other point and to fit them on the same curve would either require putting a break on the curve or making the difference in consecutive tick marks large enough to fit everything in.  But that would make it very difficult to discern differences between point in the center of the distribution.  Using a log scale eliminates this problem.